# How do i measure time taken for kafka rebalance?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am very new to Kafka. So this question might be very basic. 
What i am trying to achieve is to find out the time it takes to rebalance when a broker fails and is then added back. 
From my reading up of the documentation(`http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_restarting`). When a broker fails or is taken down for maintenance

- `It will sync all its logs to disk to avoid needing to do any log recovery when it restarts (i.e. validating the checksum for all messages in the tail of the log). Log recovery takes time so this speeds up intentional restarts.`
- `It will migrate any partitions the server is the leader for to other replicas prior to shutting down. This will make the leadership transfer faster and minimize the time each partition is unavailable to a few milliseconds.`

What i want to do is find out the time taken to `migrate any partitions that the server is the leader for to other replicas`

My kafka setup is 3 broker nodes and 3 zk nodes.

Also, when i add this node back to the property of `auto.rebalance=true` the rebalance again kicks in, and it re-elects a leader. 
How do i measure this time as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "migration" as in data copy. When shutting down a broker cleanly, the controller will simply elect a new leader from the available replicas for all partitions the broker was the leader, making the transition fast.

There are a few metrics you can monitor the leader elections. 
Since 0.11.0.0, the broker exposes a number of Controller metrics including:

```
kafka.controller:type=ControllerStats,name=AutoLeaderBalanceRateAndTimeMs
```

This tracks the rate and duration of auto leader rebalance. The full list of controller metrics that were added in 0.11 is available in the KIP:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-143%3A+Controller+Health+Metrics#KIP-143:ControllerHealthMetrics-ControllerMetrics

If you are running an older version (< 0.11.0.0), you'll have to rely on metrics like:

```
kafka.controller:type=ControllerStats,name=LeaderElectionRateAndTimeMs
```

This include any leader elections.